# Prevent a function to fire more than 3 times

Tags: javascript, function

I'm Using the code below to let my function A only be triggered 3 times. 
 as I'm new to Javascript I think maybe you guys could show me a better way.

```
var num = 0;
if(num<4){

function A() {
       num++
             }
}
```

Comment: How are you invoking the function?

Comment: That `if()` will never be true as shown. Never declare functions inside an `if()`

Comment: I'm using Web Speech API, function A invoking when "recognition.onend = function(event)" occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd put the num check inside the function, in case you want to call it anywhere else it will check your num record when you call it instead of having it automatically run 3 times when you start your program.

```
var num = 0;

function A() {
    if(num<4){
       //perform whatever you want your func to do
       num++;
    } else {
        console.log("You performed this function 3 times already");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends highly on what you want to achieve, but one way is using recursion:

```
function foo(param1, param2, count = 3) {
       if (count > 0) {
              // ... some code ...
              return foo(param1, param2, count-1)
       }
       return null; // just as example and check for the null later
}
```